# Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2008 formula to exclude rows of a dataset

Tags: crystal-reports, report, formula

I have a crystal report which evaluates data from a dataset passed from a windows forms application.
In this dataset customers_orders I have the fields day,customer_code,customer_name,customer_surname ,order_code,order_desc .
So far my formula states :

```
if  {customers_orders.customer_code} <> ""
then {customers_orders.customer_code}
```

Now I want to leave out all the rows of the dataset which have no entry for customer_code
something like:

```
if  {customers_orders.customer_code} = ""
then do nothing
```

If I leave out the second part and just go with the first formula
I get blank rows in my report.
(I edit the crystal report in visual studio 2008)
How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself but I wanted to share it with all in case someone has the same problem.
In visual studio 2008 there is a menu point called "Crystal Reports".
There you will find Report-->Section Expert...
[Screenshot Section Expert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVhT4.jpg)

And as you can see there is a simple checkbox called "Suppress Blank Section"
This worked for me